# Website breadcrumbs appear then disappear immediately - why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, breadcrumbs

I am designing a web page as I am learning web development and I have a project to complete.

As part of the web site I want to put breadcrumbs on my web page into an empty div:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs"></div>
```

To do this I am using a JavaScript function as follows. When a menu item is clicked in order to load a new page, the current page name is extracted. The function then checks sessionStorage to see if it contains anything - if not, it saves the current page name and displays it in the breadcrumbs div; if sessionStorage contains something then the current page is appended, saved and displayed.

```
// When the user clicks a menu item
function saveCurrentPageName(){
  
  // Gets name of current page
  let path = window.location.pathname;
  let page = path.split("/").pop().replace(".html","");
  if (page == "index"){
    page = "home";
  }

  let trail = sessionStorage.getItem("savedpage");
  if (trail !== null){
    sessionStorage.setItem("savedpage", trail + " - " + page);
    document.getElementById("breadcrumbs").innerHTML = trail + " - " + page;
  }
  else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("savedpage", page);
    document.getElementById("breadcrumbs").innerHTML = page;
  }
};
```

My problem is this, and it's odd - when I load the web site and click on a menu item, the breadcrumb appears in the correct place but then disappears immediately. it is correct in what is shown (briefly) but I cannot understand why it is disappearing.

The CSS for the element is:

```
.breadcrumbs {
    grid-area: B;
    display: flex;
    background-color:  #132257;
    justify-content: left;
    padding-left: 19vw;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;
}
```

I can't show a video here but here is a screenshot showing the breadcrumb trail before it immediately disappears:

[image: shot of the breadcrumb]

If anyone can explain why this is happening I'd be grateful. In the JS there is no code other than that shown which accesses sessionStorage and it is never cleared at any stage.

Comment: How is your `saveCurrentPageName()` function being called? Are the menu items links to new pages? (When you click a menu item does it redirect you to a new page?)

Comment: Have you used dev tools to see if its really not there and not hidden or moved or something?

Comment: So, the function is called from a click event for every menu list item:

// Add the saveCurrentPageName function to each item's click event
for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++){
  menuItems[i].addEventListener("click", saveCurrentPageName);
};

When the menu list item is clicked it saves the data but then a new page is loaded - I'm guessing that this new page does NOT load the saved data which is why it appears then disappears? I should do the display of breadcrumnbs AFTER the page has fully loaded?

Comment: That's what made the difference  -I added an event listener to the DOMContentLoaded event and it works perfectly... thanks Conman_123

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer (as is most often the case) was very simple:

On the click event of each menu item STORE the relevant page name.

Then, when the new page loads, call a Display function which is handled by the DOMContentLoaded event and it all works perfectly!

- Step 1 CLICK menu item
- Step 2 SAVE page name into sessionStorage
- Step 3 new page LOADS
- Step 4 after load is COMPLETE display the breadcrumbs.

Thanks to Conman_123 for asking for clarification which highlighted the correct approach.